# C# and C/C++ integration for profiling

Tags: c#, c, profiler, aop, papi

I am trying to do some profiles on some applications regarding low-level efficiency in OO 
frameworks, namely, instruction counts, cache-miss, TLB misses, and things of the sort. So far I was able to do these kind of measurements in Java mixing the [Papi profiler](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/) instrumentations with JNI and AspectJ to get the desired info.

I was wondering if anyone knows about something similar in C#, i.e., mixing C#, aspect oriented programming (AoP) and some kind calling interfaces between C and C#.

I've been googling and found there already is an AoP related framework for C# called AspectSharp, however it seems a bit complicated to configure and use it in Mono (which is what I use for C#).

So in conclusion I'm asking for help in

- AspectSharp
- C/C++ <=> C# interfaces (?)

Thanks in advance